# Problem with gray screen in Ubuntu Desktop

Tags: 16.04, server, gnome, remote-desktop, vnc

I have a Linux server with Ubuntu Server 16.04 installed, and I want to connect to it via `Nomachine` program from my windows computer or via `VNC`.

I tried to read some articles on the internet and follow the steps to install Ubuntu Desktop or GNOME desktop and after I did that, I only see a gray screen/background when I try to login via `VNC`.

When I try to login via `Nomachine`, and after I press the sign-in button, I get a gray screen that shows up for a second and then suddenly shuts down.

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Try `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop`

Comment: That's not the problem, The problem is the gray screen, Can I give you the server and take a look to it? Thanks

Comment: Can you log in normally (not through VNC)?

Comment: You mean via the shell?